# two different repositories in nexus contains the same jar

Tags: java, nexus

I have a nexus 2.1.2 installation that have a proxy repository of central.

It contains a copy of javax.ejb version 2.1, but only the pom file, that jar file is missing from both the proxy repo and maven central.

We have uploaded the jar file so a locally hosted repo on our nexus, but when I search for javax.ejb only the pom file from the proxy repo shows up.

Is it possible to get the nexus to prioritize locally hosted repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the group repository is relevant. Just put the hosted local repositories before/above the proxy.